# I'm looking for a introduction to php(5 or 6)/mysql/javascript web development book

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Basically I want the books to be text book based, ie, author discusses the background,philosophy,syntax,semtantix for every language AND after every section there are questions what you learned so far and mini projects.  Is there any books like this, I'm absolutely new to php/mysql/javascript and web development in general.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically PHP 6 doesn't exist yet. ;-)

Comment: That hasn't stopped publishers from already filling the shelves with book on the topic.

Comment: prgrmnGuru, Can you code already?  What languages? That will make a huge difference on what you should choose.

Comment: Yes I can code.  I am an expert java programmer.

Comment: @webbiedave which is a reason never to buy from these publishers anymore, because it's unprofessional

Comment: @webbidave tomorrow you'll see employers asking for 2+ years experience in php 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not single book

I know you asked for only book explaining introducing PHP/MySQL/Javascript. I am sorry I don't know one book for this. But what I have read/skimmed which I liked was the following.

### PHP

I myself really enjoyed reading [Matt zandstra's PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804). I think it is really a good book to learn good Object Oriented Programming. It directly learns you have to code good PHP instead of just picking up "an introduction to PHP" book which teaches you bad coding practices which will bite you later. I think this book isn't really for the beginners, but with a little bit of focus you could read this book.

### Javascript

My advise would be to read [Douglas Crockford's javascript the good parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748). This book explains what part of javascript you should use because they are good and which parts are best to avoid because they aren't that good.

### MySQL

I think you should learn the basics about PDO(PHP Data Objects) reading [Dennis Popl's Learning PHP Data Objects](https://www.packtpub.com/Learning-PHP-Data-Objects-Open-Source/book).

Answer (score 2):

Skim through few preview pages of *Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript* from O'Reilly on Google Books - http://books.google.com/books?id=Zwzc4qUZnqMC&printsec=frontcover and see if it's what you are looking for. This book, along with PHP documentation should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Larry Ullman's PHP 6 and MySQL 5 Visual Quick Pro Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-MySQL-Dynamic-Web-Sites/dp/032152599X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1270583353&sr=8-1), it's not a one stop shop for everything php and mysql based, but it provides a strong foundation which is very quick to grasp! Also contains some useful tips at the end of each subject, which have helped me many a time!

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend Javascript The Definitive Guide as a reference - http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992.

This book has saved me many days of work, but it's a reference and not a textbook-style questions and answers book.

Answer (score 1):

I know this ressource is not a book, but anyway take a look at: 
http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner

The site contains 15 well-described chapters about PHP.

What I really like is the introductory comments to each chapter, because they really describe the various topics in plain english and give you a solid and broad understanding.